# How to unset the positional parameters?

Tags: shell, parameter

How do I do this:

```
set foo bar baz
unset # Something else here
echo $# # Should ouput 0
```

By doing `set ""`, `$#` will still be 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok this was just stupid, and I found out using `set --` will work.

Comment: @Gilles: According to the bash man page, `set -` with no arguments leaves the positional parameters unchanged.

Comment: @camh I must disagree. I see this in the manual:           set   --      If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset.  Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the args, even if some of them begin
                      with a -.

Comment: @kdubs you are quoting the man page for `set --`. I have used `set -` (single hyphen), which says: "If there are no args, the positional parameters remain unchanged."

Comment: you are right. I got them confused. my screen made your - look like --

Answer (score 6):

Easily unset all positional parameters with:

```
shift $#
```

To remove the first 3 positional parameters:

```
shift 3
```

Shift "pops" off the first N positional parameters. By using $# we get the total number of positional parameters. The command thus pops off all the positional parameters.